# How to extract numbers from a string column and determine whether they are less than a threshold?

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, stringr

So I have the following df:

```
df=data.frame(strength=c("10MG;50MG","2MG;5MG","1MG,5MG","100MG;1UG"))
```

I want to tag the rows which have <5 MG,
this is what I have done but it's not working, I get the error

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% mutate(new=as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(strength, "[0-9]+"))),check=any(which(new<5)))
```

Comment: Something like `df$new <- stringr::str_detect(df$strength, "(?<!\\d)[1-4]MG\\b")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, why doesn't str_extract_all work in this case? I need to convert other units to MG before I check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_extract_all` returns a list so if you `unlist` them you will lose the information about which value comes from which row. Keep them in a list and then use `rowwise` or one of the `map` function to iterate over each list to check if `any` value is less than 5 in that row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = stringr::str_extract_all(strength, "[0-9]+")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(check = any(as.numeric(new) < 5))

# strength  new       check
#  <chr>     <list>    <lgl>
#1 10MG;50MG <chr [2]> FALSE
#2 2MG;5MG   <chr [2]> TRUE 
#3 1MG,5MG   <chr [2]> TRUE 
#4 100MG;1UG <chr [2]> TRUE
```